# CheckListBox previewkeydown not fired with mouse buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouse

When I use the mouse click event in a checkboxlist, the result is depending on the previous selection. Thus I need the previewkeydown with a mouse event.

No compile or runtime errors.
But this doesn't work. Event is working with all other keys but not mouse keys !

Any Help ?

```
private void chckListBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LButton)
        MessageBox.Show(" click ");
        // process code here 
    }
```

Comment: Mousebuttons are not keys.  This will not work.  You need MouseDown or MouseUp.

Answer (score 0):

as @DonBoitnott said, use standard winform `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` event to capture the mouse clicks

like

```
private void frm_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) 
{
      // write your code
}
```